# Is there a built in way to reduce the amount of points in an IElement

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, c#, .net, generalization

I have a polyline element and I want to reduce the number of points (vertices?) that make up the line. I know it will make the curved sections jagged and that is fine. I just want to control (perhaps by a percentage of the total?) how many points are decimated. I looked at the ITopologicalOperator.Simplify method but this does not seem to be what I need.

Comment: Have you looked at the [IPolycurve.Generalize](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Generalize_Method/002m000002m5000000/) method, which uses a specified maximum offset tolerance?

Comment: There is also [Weed](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Weed_Method/002m000002m9000000/).  If you need to specify how many points are decimated, you may have to make several passes, keeping track of how many vertices are retained until you are happy with the results (i.e. total count, percentage of total, etc).

Comment: That sounds like the answer @Barbarossa. ITopoloigalOperatorX.Simplify doesn't reduce the number of vertices, think of simplify more like *validate* which fixes self intersections and incorrect orientations (like Repair Geometry) which isn't so important to an IElement geometry but is absolutely vital for geometries stored in an enterprise database - the database will refuse to store or update a geometry that isn't simple. Simplify has no meaning for point and multipoint geometries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [IPolycurve.Generalize](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Generalize_Method/002m000002m5000000/) or [IPolycurve.Weed](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Weed_Method/002m000002m9000000/) methods.  Both use a specified maximum offset tolerance.  If, however, you need to specify how many points are decimated, you can make several passes over your geometry, using Generalize/Weed to reduce the vertex count, keeping track of this count until you are happy with the results.